# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу: файл занят другим процессом

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, tkinter

Хотел создать что-то по типу builder на python, у меня была такая задумка: создать текстовый документ в него вписать код после чего переиминовать файл txt в py и ввести в cmd с помощью subprocess команду cd и директорию файла, после чего командой pyinstaller откомпилировать файл в exe, но когда я запустил builder возникла вот такая ошибка:

```
        Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in 
    __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\epicb\Desktop\Sherat\Sherik.py", line 243, in <lambda>
        b = tk.Button(self, text='build', command=lambda: buildsettings(self))
      File "C:\Users\epicb\Desktop\Sherat\Sherik.py", line 191, in buildsettings
            os.rename("C://Sherik/" + name + ".txt", "C://Sherik" + name + ".py")
        PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят 
        другим процессом: 'C://Sherik/name.txt' -> 'C://Sherikname.py'
```

вот код отвечающий за создание билда:

```
file = open("C:\Sherik/" + name + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file.write("import subprocess\n")
file.write("")
file.write("try:\n")
file.write("text = subprocess.check_output(\n")
file.write("['ipconfig'],\n")
file.write("stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,\n")
file.write(").decode('cp866')\n")
file.write("except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:\n")
file.write("text = str(e)\n")
file.write("text = text.splitlines()[18][39:]")
os.rename("C://Sherik/" + name + ".txt", "C://Sherik" + name + ".py")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.close()` перед перемещением

Answer (score 2):

Не закрыт файл после записи. Сделайте:

```
file.close()
```

И пользуйтесь [менеджерами контекста](https://python-scripts.com/contextlib):

```
with open(path, 'w') as f_obj:
    f_obj.write(some_data)
```